# In CloudFormation How do I reference the VPC Id from a chosen subnet id?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am creating an EC2 instance with a CF template, and will choose the subnet as on3 of my parameters. Once I have chosen the subnet, is there a way for CloudFormation to find the VPC id of the Subnet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't an easy way to just get the VPC Id automatically from a Subnet Id, CloudFormation limitation at the moment. You have two main options for getting around this:

**Easiest option:** Pass in VPC Id parameter that matches your Subnet Id.

**Harder option:** Create a custom resource, lambda is usually the easiest way, that gets the VPC Id from the Subnet Id. Amazon has a [sample on creating a custom resource to look values up](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html).

Looking around I found [someone has built a library](https://github.com/lucioveloso/cli2cloudformation) for executing CLI commands from a Lambda custom resource. This could be a good option if building your own lambda function a bit much.